# Vimdiff functionality in Sublime Text 2

Tags: vim, sublime-text-2, diff, vimdiff

I wanted to know if it is possible to have a `vimdiff` like functionality to check for `diff` and have `synchronized scrolling` of two (or more) files in Sublime Text 2 just like vimdiff?

Thanks

Comment: What did you find on Google?

Comment: @romainl, I actually did not find anything useful in google. Thats the reason I posted on superuser

Comment: I try https://github.com/colinta/SublimeFileDiffs , this plugin compares files, but this don't have the side-by-side diff .

Comment: @juanpablo yep. Even I'm using the same plugin for the time being. Maybe I'll build it soon. Shouldn't be too hard :) ;)

Answer (score -1):

I use [Compare Side-By-Side](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Compare%20Side-By-Side) on a daily basis to compare two files in Sublime Text 3. I haven't tested it on Sublime Text 2, but their [site](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Compare%20Side-By-Side) claims that it works on both Sublime Text 2 and 3.

From their site:

> Compare Side-By-Side:
>   Side-by-side file comparison & difference tool for ST2/3

Features:

> - Easily select two tabs or selections to compare
> - Comparison results open in a new window
> - Empty lines added so common code lines up
> - Count number of lines changed
> - Highlighting of changed lines
> - Intra-line diff highlighting
> - **Synchronized scrolling**

Installation Options:

> - Search for and install using Sublime Package Control (ctrl+shift+P, “Install Package”)
> - Clone or extract this repo to a new folder in your Sublime 'Packages' folder
>     (Preferences -> Browse Packages)

More details can be found [here](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Compare%20Side-By-Side)

Comment: Can you go into a little more detail on how to use this plugin to achieve the results the OP is after? Please see [answer] and take our [tour].

Comment: Please read [How do I recommend software](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers/5330#5330) for some tips as to how you should go about recommending software. You should provide at least a link, some additional information about the software itself, and how it can be used to solve the problem in the question.